Access DevOps API with application delegation
Is there any way to access the Azure Devops REST API with a service principal? In the API permissions there is only user delegated permissions:

We need do do some scraping of projects and tasks. And have only succeeded with a users security token. And we need to do it with a service account that can access everything.


Is there any way to access the Azure Devops REST API with a service principal?

Yes. You can refer to the following steps to generate the access token to run the Rest API:
Step1: Go to Organization Settings > Azure Active Directory, ensure the Organization has connected to the AAD which the Service Principal is in.
Step2: Go to Organization Settings > Users, search and add the Service Principal into the Organization.
Step3: After successfully adding the Service Principal into the Organization, add it into a group so that you can manage the permissions of the Service Principal through that group in the Organization.
Step4: We can generate the access token with the Service Principal credential.
Bash Script:
access_token=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
-d 'client_id={client_id}&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials' | jq -r '.access_token')

(1)Replace {tenant_ID} with the Directory (tenant) ID of AAD.
(2)Replace {client_id} with the Application (client) ID of the Service Principal.
(3)Replace {client_secret} with the value of the client secret created in the Service Principal
PowerShell:
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>

Write-Host "Obtain access token for Service Connection identity..."
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 --query "accessToken" --output tsv

Write-Host "Use access token with Azure DevOps REST API to list projects in the organization..."
$apiVersion = "7.1-preview.1"
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/${yourOrgname}/_apis/projects?api-version=${apiVersion}"
$headers = @{
    Accept = "application/json"
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value ` | Select-Object id, name

Postman:

The access token can be directly used to run Azure DevOps Rest APIs.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Add and manage service principals in an Azure DevOps organization
